# Regex PHP: to look ahead twice

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

Why this:

```
/^lol(?=abc)(?=dfg)$/
```

can't match this

```
lolabcdfg
```

Thank you for your answer! It was very kind of you!

Comment: Good documentation on lookaheads can be found on [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because lookaheads only assert, they do not consume characters... so basically you're saying,

match lol:

```
lol
```

then look head for abc:

```
lol(abc) // matches
```

now look ahead for dfg

```
lol(dfg) // does not match
```

This is why it's not working. You need to consume the characters, if you want to check for both abc and abcdfg. If you only want to look ahead you can do:

```
/^lol(?=abc|dfg|abcdfg)/
```

This will match the strings

- lolabc
- loldfg
- lolabcdfg

However it's not very useful. The following would be more appropriate

```
/^lol(abc)?(dfg)?/
```

Which would match lol, optionally abc then optionally dfg.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do

```
/^lol(abc)?(dfg)?$/
```

I always use https://regex101.com/ to test my regex online

Comment: Why so? I can't understand(

Comment: But this wasn't the question... you can also use `/^lolabcdfg$/`

Comment: @V.Terte use the regex I send you in the url I've also pasted in the message and you will get a nice explanation on how that regex works

Comment: An explanation should be included with an answer.